# I can't connect to Ubuntu server from local network, but can from outside

Tags: networking, server, ssh, iptables, firewall

This is a weird one that has been driving me crazy for a while. I just can't work it out.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 (with all latest patches) on a Dell PowerEdge-r710 server. It's hosting a variety of services on a variety of ports. Many are being run under Kubernetes, some are directly under the host. This is on a domestic LAN behind a Verizon router. I've used port forwarding on the router to route all the ports of interest to the machine and that all works just fine.

What doesn't work, is when I try to access those ports from the internal network. It used to work, but now it doesn't.

Here are some example cases:

- Example 1, native service. I can `ssh -p 8022 jo@publicname.com` just fine from inside or outside my house. But when I try `ssh -p 8022 jo@192.168.1.173` from inside the house, it can't connect. Unless I do it from the command line of the server itself.
- Example 2, Kubernetes hosted web server. I can `curl http://publicname.com:8181` fine, but `curl http://192.168.1.173:8181` does not work. Ditto for working from the shell of the server.
- Example 3, the odd one out: `ping publicname.com` works fine, but so does `ping 192.168.1.173`. O_o

I have tried this from multiple machines inside the house. I have tried it from Windows machines and Mac machines. It's all the same. So I'm assuming it isn't workstation dependent.

I've tried it with the local name, but I'm just using the internal IP address here, to take DNS out of the equation. I've tried it when both the server are plugged into a switch, downstream from the router. I've rebooted my router. I don't generally make many settings to my router (other than port forwarding) and there's been no firmware upgrade for it for at least a year. So I'm pretty sure it isn't a router problem.

I've both enabled and disabled UFW, and it doesn't seem to matter. With UFW off, I've tried adding explicit access to, say `8022`:

```
*A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8022 -j ACCEPT*
```

No help.

There's a lot of other UFW, Docker, and Kubernetes rules in `iptables` (and `iptables-legacy`) which I can dump if it would be of use.

Here is a dump from `ip -4 route list`:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno4 proto static metric
100  blackhole 10.1.23.128/26 proto 80 
10.1.23.136 dev cali83503037a1d scope link 
10.1.23.137 dev cali94b8c5e0ec2 scope link 
10.1.23.141 dev caliebd7497b285 scope link 
10.1.23.142 dev cali224b6f89d2e scope link 
10.1.23.143 dev calia147e44c90e scope link 
10.1.23.146 dev caliebea71cd4c0 scope link 
10.1.23.147 dev calief22f96cfc6 scope link 
10.1.23.149 dev calif356e5d735e scope link 
10.1.23.154 dev cali9a9cf33aad8 scope link 
10.1.23.155 dev cali0ce1e6d1dc6 scope link 
10.1.23.156 dev cali5a5d94e5703 scope link 
10.1.23.159 dev calib51c35c69e3 scope link 
10.1.23.160 dev cali05a64ae21b6 scope link 
10.1.23.174 dev cali6d73584524e scope link 
10.1.23.179 dev cali3df919b30be scope link 
10.1.23.181 dev cali6eba53f48ff scope link 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eno4 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.1 dev eno4 proto static scope link metric 100
```

Here's a dump of the IP address:

```
$ ip addr show dev eno4
5: eno4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:2b:2b:61:b1:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0f1
    inet 192.168.1.173/32 scope global noprefixroute eno4
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::862b:2bff:fe61:b196/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I've put up with this for about a month now, while trying to work it. For ssh I can deal. But I've added a SAMBA drive for backups and I really don't want to expose that to the internet just so I can get to it from my LAN.

Does any of this make sense to anyone?

Comment: Can you show the output of `ip -4 route list` in your system?  Are you running docker, etc. on that system with the possibility of an IP conflict between the system bridges and the network you're on?  (happens regularly here, it's why i have to reconfigure those to be in a different subnet range)

Comment: @ThomasWard
Kubernetes does all sorts of crazy network things I barely understand. So you may be right. Attaching output.

Comment: @ArturMeinild, 167 is a typo. Corrected above, and ip dump added. Also I've tried with both the server and workstation plugged into the same switch, and different switches. I've clarified the question with that as well.

Comment: Did you try traceroute from your workstation to 192.168.1.173 ? Does it try to reach the server directly or goes to some strange places ?

Comment: @raj It goes direct from both my Mac and Windows machine plugged into the same switch.

Comment: Well, then definitely something must block the connection on your server. I see one strange thing in the routing table you posted. If `192.168.1.0/24` is your local LAN, there should be a route to it, but there isn't. There's only a point-to-point route to `192.168.1.1`. Probably because your IP adddress `192.168.1.173` has a mask `/32` instead of `/24`. So my guess is your server instead of sending a reply directly to requesting machine, tries to send it via default route to your router, and the router is unable to send it back. Try to fix your routing.

Comment: @raj I think you're right. Joseph, if you include your Netplan config in your question we can see if the wrong subnet range is set here, or if it's configured by DHCP in your gateway ("router").

Comment: That was *exactly* it @raj. I changed my IP address to a static address in about the right timeframe that things went wrong. And, sure enough, I had a netmask of 255.255.255.255. I've changed it to 255.255.255.0, and I can connect from the local LAN. MANY THANKS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raj's comment gave me an idea. It seems you have somehow defined your local IP address with a `/32` subnet, as seen in the output of `ip addr show dev eno4`:

> ```
> 5: eno4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
>     link/ether 84:2b:2b:61:b1:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>     altname enp2s0f1
>     inet 192.168.1.173/32 scope global noprefixroute eno4
>        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
>     inet6 fe80::862b:2bff:fe61:b196/64 scope link 
>        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
> ```

This means that the network has only a single IPv4 address and all traffic will go directly between the device with that IPv4 address and the default gateway ([see here](https://superuser.com/questions/1473252/what-does-it-mean-to-have-a-subnet-mask-32)), again supporting Raj's comment.

So you should fix this in your network configuration. Most home networks use a `/24` subnet (`255.255.255.0` subnet mask) to allow for the forth octet to be used as IP addresses (gives 254 possible IP addresses in the range).

Since it doesn't make sense for a DHCP server to hand out IP addresses in a `/32` subnet range, I think this is a wrong configuration in your Netplan (here assuming that you have set a static IP for the server). So set the subnet mask of your static IP to `255.255.255.0` instead of `255.255.255.255`.

Comment: Thank you for writing up Raj's answer. This sorted it out for me.